# BitBucket Git Branches model

Tags: git, bitbucket

I don't understand , why i can't see splitted branches in bitbucket (website).So i downloaded SourceTree where everything is ok. But i want to know how make branches in web version like  at second picture (SourceTree)
[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with GitHub - why the [tag:github] tag?

Comment: This portfolio is more of a personal dashboard. You need to change to the git project and start a branch from there. It might also be possible from your "Branches" menu option.